# In the Rosh Chodesh leining, why is "Shabbas b'Shabato" pronounced with a pasach?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, rosh-chodesh-new-month, pinchas

Recently, I paid attention to the Rosh Chodesh Torah reading (Bamidbar/Numbers Chapter 28) and noticed that in verse 10, "olas Shabbas b'Shabato…", the word "Shabbas" is vowelized with a pasach (short o as in "pot") under the bais. Usually, the word has a kamatz (short u as in "dug") under the bais, being read "Shabbus", and transliterated as "Shabbos."
A pasach in this manner usually indicates a s'michus, meaning that the word is connected to the following word, typically as a description. Here, though, "Shabbas" does not appear to be describing the next word, "b'Shabato".

So why the unusual vowelization?

Comment: I believe this is just a masoretic quirk. Your thoughts are correct.

Comment: I think that when the word "Shabbat" is followed by an adjective, it gets a patach. See the consistency in the Torah's use of "Shabbat Shaboton" - The 1st Shabbat has a patach as it is followed by the "adjective" - Shabbaton (what kind of Shabbat? a "Shabbaton" or "double" Shabbat.) In a sense, "Shabbat B'Shabbato" the "B'SHabbato" could be considered an adjective as the meaning of teh phrase means, "each Shabbat". BTW - The same patach is used in speech in the phrase "Shabbat Shalom" - "Shalom" is an adjective.

Comment: @DanF Are you sure the phrase Shabbat Shalom is like that? Perhaps it is just the Sefardic and Modern Israeli tendency of pronouncing Patach and Kamatz the same

Comment: @DoubleAA - I had forgotten about this Q. You raise a good point, here. I'm still inclined to stick to my original analysis, though. Another example to support the Patach - from Zemirot - "Shabbat Kodesh Hayom Chemdato" (Patach - Kodesh is an adj.)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a Masoretic quirk. The Masorah (in the ["Damascus Keter"](http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/mss/heb5702/index_eng.html)) for that verse notes this unusual occurance and lists the other places in Tanakh where שבת is punctuated this way.

[image: manuscript masorah notes to numbers 28 10]

> [The word] Shabbat [thus punctuated appears] 4 [times]. And their mnemonic: [Vehayta](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm#6) [Olat](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm#10) [Lehakhin](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a09.htm#32) [Kodshecha](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b09.htm#14). And all [[instances](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0231.htm#15) [of](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0235.htm#2) [the](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0316.htm#31) [phrase](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#3)] [Shabbat](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#32) [Shabbaton](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm) [are also thus punctuated].

Comment: What makes something a "quirk"?

Comment: @Yishai ungrammaticalness.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50258&st=&pgnum=329